# Using push() method to create new child location without unique key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase web app when new users signup with their email i create a node under their email adress under the root ref

But the problem is  using push() method to add every new user to the database every user is created with a unique key like below

-**users**

----**ASFTU578FE**

---------user: user1@email.com

----**FDWWE36S46**

---------user: user2@email.com

----**WERSRTT23W**

---------user: user3@email.com

Now how can i access the path for a user since i dont know the unque key that will be created for every new user

Is there a way to push new user without a unique key but the key i know like user.displayName or user.email

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Calling `push` generates a location with an auto-calculated key.

To write a child at a path that you determine the key yourself, you simply call `child("key").set(value)`.

If you store Firebase Authentication users in your database, the idiomatic way is to store them under their uid.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
if (user) {
  usersRef.child(user.uid).set({ 
    displayName: displayName,
    email: email,
    photoUrl: photoUrl,
    emailVerified: emailVerified
  });
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. @Vamsi Krishna consider users could change their e-mail address in the future. The uid stays stable for such use cases.

Comment: I was going through the docs many times ,, it was mentioned only how to refer to a child but not crating a child,,,, thank you very much,,,and another problem is if i add the child with user.email its noot working but working with user.uid,,, dont know why,,,,once again thank you very much

Comment: Nodes in the tree are created as you write values and removed as you delete values. So there's no way to explicitly create or remove a node.

Comment: @rkrish It is because in Hashmap<key,values> you cannot store string in Key attribute which have "." in it thats why you cannot able to add email in child. Since uid dont have any "." string in it thats why it can be added as child. Upvote the answer if you found this useful.