# Post request to firebase without unique key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to post new data to my firebase API, but everytime I do so, a new key, like `-L545gZW7E6Ed6iqXRok` is generated with my object inside it. I would like to save my object directly to the API without this new key. [This SO question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885707/using-push-method-to-create-new-child-location-without-unique-key) how to do it using the set() method, but I would like to achieve this using Postman. I am posting directly to firebase using Postman. 
url: `https://my-firebase-project.firebaseio.com/galaxies.json` with method POST.

```js
//current saving like this in firebase
"0000001" : {
  "active": false,
  "name": "tp-milky-way",
  "time": 60
},
"-L545gZW7E6Ed6iqXRok": {
 "0000011": {
      "active": false,
      "name": "tp-andromeda",
      "time": 60
    }
}

//I want it without the key
"0000001" : {
  "active": false,
  "name": "tp-milky-way",
  "time": 60
},
"0000011" : {
  "active": false,
  "name": "tp-andromeda",
  "time": 60
}
```

EDIT: I found out I can use PUT with the entire json object that was originally 'put' to firebase with the additions or deletions, and firebase compares the new put request with what's already on there and updates accordingly. I don't know the behaviour is as I understand it or if there isn't a better way to add data without auto-generated keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use the [`POST` verb](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-post), Firebase generates a new location. This is in line with REST-ful idioms: `POST` is used to create a new object in a server-defined new location.

If you want to write to an existing location, or a new location you control, use the [`PUT` verb](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put). In this case the data will be written to exactly the location you specify in the URL, and it will overwrite any existing data at that location.

If you want to update part of the data at an existing location, but leave other pieces of the data unmodified, use the [`PATCH` verb](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update).

If your HTTP client doesn't support specifying a verb, you can optionally [pass the verb as `HTTP-Method-Override` header](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put).